# Please provide a valid IP address/host name

Tags: scanner

I installed scanner software for a wireless Lexmark multifunction printer. I call up simple scan and it asks for a valid IP address/host name. How do I do that? I have restarted the computer and unplugged and replugged the router.

Comment: I believe you can find this in the printers control panel.

Comment: Don't know about Lexmark, but Brother has special drivers that need to be installed  if you want to use their scanner wireless (not needed with usb)

Answer (score 0):

Is the printer installed in Ubuntu as a printer? If so go to settings, and the hostname may be whatever your printer is named. `ping` that to get the IP. Or in settings click `Additional Printer Settings` then right-click on the printer and choose `Properties`. The IP address may be on the end of the `Device URI`.

Or:
Try running `lpoptions` or `lpinfo -v` or `lpstat -s` in a terminal window.

Or:
If the printer has a display then you should be able to see the current IP address that is assigned by going into the options/menus. Or print a status page which should also show network details.